# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'regional' of undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, calendar

I am using jQuery UI Calender for French Language. 
But unfortunately I see the below error not sure if I am missing some thing. 
Please advice.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'regional' of undefined**

```
 JS : 
/**
French initialisation for the jQuery UI date picker plugin. 
**/
/* Written by Keith Wood (kbwood{at}iinet.com.au),
              Stéphane Nahmani (sholby@sholby.net),
              Stéphane Raimbault <stephane.raimbault@gmail.com> */
jQuery(function($){
    $.datepicker.regional['fr'] = {
        closeText: 'Fermer',
        prevText: 'Précédent',
        nextText: 'Suivant',
        currentText: 'Aujourd\'hui',
        monthNames: ['Janvier','Février','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin',
        'Juillet','Août','Septembre','Octobre','Novembre','Décembre'],
        monthNamesShort: ['Janv.','Févr.','Mars','Avril','Mai','Juin',
        'Juil.','Août','Sept.','Oct.','Nov.','Déc.'],
        dayNames: ['Dimanche','Lundi','Mardi','Mercredi','Jeudi','Vendredi','Samedi'],
        dayNamesShort: ['Dim.','Lun.','Mar.','Mer.','Jeu.','Ven.','Sam.'],
        dayNamesMin: ['D','L','M','M','J','V','S'],
        weekHeader: 'Sem.',
        dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
        firstDay: 1,
        isRTL: false,
        showMonthAfterYear: false,
        yearSuffix: ''};
    $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['fr']);
});
```

Thanks!!

Comment: That message seems to be telling you that `$.datepicker ` is not defined. Have you included the jQuery UI script on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you forgot to include the localisation file:

```
<script src="https://jquery-ui.googlecode.com/svn-history/r3982/trunk/ui/i18n/jquery.ui.datepicker-nl.js"></script>
```

Source :[Datepicker jQuery UI ... set language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332445/datepicker-jquery-ui-set-language)

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to do not use ASYNC on script tags, because will fire this error.

Wrong:

```
<SCRIPT SRC="/includes/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js" TYPE="text/javascript" ASYNC></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT SRC="/includes/js/jquery/jquery-datepicker-ptBR.js" TYPE="text/javascript" ASYNC></SCRIPT>
```

Right:

```
<SCRIPT SRC="/includes/js/jquery/jquery-ui.js" TYPE="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT SRC="/includes/js/jquery/jquery-datepicker-ptBR.js" TYPE="text/javascript"></SCRIPT>
```