# Customizing jQuery ui datepicker width

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery ui datepicker to show datepicker when someone clicks on the input with the help of following code snippet.

**Code:**

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/KiranKumarDash/jkg6h6sc/)

The problem I have with this is that the calendar should come as full width of the input before it.

I did search the internet and used a few code snippets but none worked.

**My approach:**

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function(input, inst)
    {
        inst.dpDiv.css({ width: input.width + 'px'});
    }
});
```

In the Fiddle the input's width is fixed as 500px, so datepicker width should also be 500px wide. And datepicker's width should adapt to whatever width is of this input.

Comment: can you post a working code snippet in your question?

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1865091/jquery-datepicker-language,    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332445/datepicker-jquery-ui-set-language,

Comment: Thanks @RanjeetSingh. That helped me to change the language.

Comment: mine pleasure. happy coding :)

Comment: @KiranKumarDash *"the calendar should come as full width of the input before it"* - We don't know which jQuery UI theme you're using, (*This isn't how default date picker looks like*) we don't  have the input or it's styling, or the customization you did... Please create a [mcve] so that we can see the problem...

Comment: @TJ. Please check again. I have made some edits and provided the jsfiddle to focus only on the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can adjust the calendar size using the below CSS:

```js
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
```

```css
#datepicker,
.ui-datepicker,
.ui-datepicker-header,
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  width: 500px;
}
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  background: dodgerblue;
}
.ui-datepicker-header {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
}
.ui-datepicker-prev {
  float: left;
}
.ui-datepicker-next {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

Comment: But that will make the width of datepicker fixed. Instead of that I would like to have a jquery script that will make it's width adapt to width of the input.

Comment: @KiranKumarDash  How is the input's width going to change? You can apply the same changes to datepicker as well... why not?  Unless you're creating a plugin on top of jQuery UI (*which you are likely not*) I don't see that being a problem. There is something going on behind the hoods that is preventing/clearing the inline width being set by script.

Comment: The input's width is actually mentioned in percentage for my case. So, currently I am trying to write some script to first get the width of input and then assign that width to datepicker.

Answer (score 2):

Datepicker show function unfortunately resets width parameter, even one set in "beforeShow" callback. To fix this we can move it after show on JS Call Stack by setTimeout().

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            inst.dpDiv.outerWidth($(input).outerWidth());
        },0);
    },
})
```

Comment: Code only answers arent encouraged as they dont provide much information for future readers please provide some explanation to what you have written